# How to make a regular expression pattern consider a comma before the start of line when using the ^ operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

#example 1  with a  ,  before capture group
input_text = "Hello how are you?, dfdfdfd fdfdfdf other text. hghhg"

#example 2 without a  , (or \.|,|;|\n) before capture group
input_text = "dfdfdfd fdfdfdf other text. hghhg"

#No matter what position you place ^ within the options, it always considers it first, ignoring the others.
fears_and_panics_match = re.search(
                                    r"(?:\.|,|;|\n|^)\s*(?:(?:for|by)\s*me|)\s*(.+?)\s*(?:other\s*text)\s*(?:\.|,|;|\n)", 
                                    #r"(?:\.|,|;|\n)\s*(?:(?:for|by)\s*me|)\s*(.+?)\s*(?:other\s*text)\s*(?:\.|,|;|\n|$)", 
                                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)


if fears_and_panics_match: print(fears_and_panics_match.group(1))
```

Why do I use this pattern `r"(?:\.|,|;|\n|^)\s*(?:(?:for|by)\s*me|)\s*(.+?)\s*(?:other\s*text)\s*(?:\.|,|;|\n)"`  capture `Hello how are you?, dfdfdfd fdfdfdf` no matter what position you place the `^`.
I would need you to evaluate the possibility of finding a comma `,` and then the one at the beginning of the line `^`

Correct output in each case:

```
#for example 1
"dfdfdfd fdfdfdf"

#for example 2
"dfdfdfd fdfdfdf"
```

Comment: The order of alternatives around `|` doesn't matter. It matches whichever alternative is found first in the input, as long as it allows the rest of the the pattern to match.

Comment: @Barmar What do you suggest that I could do so that the regex pattern gives priority to the punctuation marks and that if none are found, then in that circumstance it should try to match the beginning of the string ^ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to optionally match some characters up to a `.`, `,` or `;`; then capture from there until `other text`:

```
^(?:.*?[.,;])?\s*(?:(?:for|by)\s*me\s*)?(\w.*?)(?=\s*other\s*text)
```

It matches:

- `^` beginning of line
- `(?:.*?[.,;])?` an optional string of characters finishing with a `.`, `,` or `;`
- `\s*` some spaces
- `(?:(?:for|by)\s*me\s*)?` the optional phrase `for me` or `by me`
- `(\w.*?)` a minimal number of characters, starting with a word character
- `(?=\s*other\s*text)` lookahead that asserts the next characters are `other text`

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/o1Btt1/1)

In python (note by using `re.match` we don't need the `^` in the regex):

```
strs = [
  'dfdfdfd fdfdfdf other text. hghhg',
  'Hello how are you?, dfdfdfd fdfdfdf other text.hghhg',
  'for me a word other text',
  'A semicolon first; then some words before other text'
]
regex = r'(?:.*?[.,;])?\s*(?:(?:for|by)\s*me\s*)?(\w.*?)(?=\s*other\s*text)'
for s in strs:
    print(re.match(regex, s).group(1))
```

Output:

```
dfdfdfd fdfdfdf
dfdfdfd fdfdfdf
a word
then some words before
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you used the wrong operator.
Also caret means "beggining of" - you never specified what should be in this beginning, so my wild guess is it took any character

no idea how much that is helpful to you - i try to keep my regexes as dumb as possible - makes it easier for me to spot the issue.

This worked on a string you provided

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9\s\?]*,?\s*(\w\s)*(?=other\stext)"
```